# Getting zsh command not found wp-scripts error

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, command-line, zsh

I'm setting up the React app inside WordPress (following Zac Gordon's tutorial). I have installed the wp-scripts by running `npm install @wordpress/scripts` and I also ran `npm install` but when trying to run `wp-scripts start`, I keep on getting error: **zsh: command not found: wp-scripts**

I'm not sure if zsh file needs any particular path added or how can I resolve this issue.
Those are my export paths:

```
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$NAME:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
# Path to Composer
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
# Path to Homebrew
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
# Path to Node
# export PATH="/Users/klara1/.nvm/versions/node/v16.11.1/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Any idea what else needs to be done here to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the point in adding `/usr/local/sbin` a zillion times to your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get this going but I will give you two options based on what you mentioned you did.

1. Install like so:

```
npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev
```

Then add these lines to your "scripts" section in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "wp-scripts start",
  "build": "wp-scripts build"
}
```

You may need to add more items as you go and can find examples on this reference page: [WP packages-scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#setup)

Now you can run the scripts you create by the name you gave it, such as "start" or "build" like so:

```
npm run start
```

2. Alternative install globally with the -g/--global option to the npm install command.

```
npm install -g @wordpress/scripts
```

And you can run the way you described as:

```
wp-scripts start
```

As "wp-scripts" gets installed as a global executable and becomes available from anywhere.

Comment: Which directory does npm put `wp-scripts` into?

Comment: @user1934428 'wp-scripts' is a package and if you install it without the global option, it will be in the 'node-modules' directory where you installed it from. Otherwise you can run 'npm list -g' to see what global modules are installed and the location on disk.